# Safely extract only directory path from file path and create directory if not exists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there anyway safely we can extract directory path from file and create directory if not exists

Example:

```
path = "/a/b/c/d/e/f/1.txt"
extract_directory_path_only = path.split("/")[0:-1]
dir = "/".join(extract_directory_path_only)
Path(dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True))
```

Comment: Look into `pathlib`

Comment: I searched, could not able to pointed right link, let me delete this post